Python cx_oracle/oracledb log bad records
After executing,
cursor.executemany("insert into table(col1, col2, col3) values (:1, :2, :3"), data, batcherrors = True)
connection.commit()
for errorobj in cursor.getbatcherrors():
I want to load the bad records from the list data as a pipe delimited string into a table with three columns run_date, data_string, error.
is this possible?

Can you clarify what you need? You want to include the bad data from the data variable in the data_string variable?

(i) Use python-oracledb instead of the older cx_Oracle.  (ii) use batcherrors as discussed in the doc https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#handling-data-errors

in the exception, is it possible to use executemany method to load error records in one shot than a loop based processing? and yes, error records has to go in as a pipe delimited string into a error table with two columns error_date and error_data_string.
